# Cannot run node with rosrun but only python

Tags: python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have an arm based system, with ubuntu 18.04 running `melodic`. I have a sample code to run a node that only publishes an array defied in a custom message:

```
 import rospy
from dma.msg import dma_data

def dma_loop():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('DMA_output', dma_data, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(2) # 10hz
    vec = dma_data()
    num = 0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        #hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        #rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        #pub.publish(hello_str)
        num = num + 1
        if num>251:
            num=0
        vec.array = [num, num, num, num, num]
        #for i in range(5):
        #    vec.array[i] = num
        pub.publish(vec)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        dma_loop()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

After running `catkin_make` and sourcing `devel/setup.bash` if I run rosrun, I get:

```
xilinx@pynq:~$ rosrun dma loop.py 
/home/xilinx/catkin_ws/src/dma/scripts/loop.py: line 1: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/dma.msg
/home/xilinx/catkin_ws/src/dma/scripts/loop.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/xilinx/catkin_ws/src/dma/scripts/loop.py: line 4: `def dma_loop():'
```

However, if I execute it directly with python it works and I can echo the topic that it publishes. Is there something else to do?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362347/cannot-run-node-with-rosrun-but-only-python/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's very likely your script is not executable.

It also doesn't have a shebang.

Run `chmod +x loop.py`  and add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the shebang.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-25**:
And note: this is not ROS specific.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2020-09-25**:
I missed the `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Thanks for the answer.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2020-09-25**:
I don't know if I should open a new thread for this.... I want to include in the same python code that only works with `sudo python3.6 script.py`. That would not work here, right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-25**:
Please search for older Q&As around this topic (use Google: append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query).

The answer is *not* using `sudo`.

Give the user that starts the node access to the resource instead.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2020-09-25**:
`sudo` could be circumvented if I understood what you mean by "Give the user that starts the node access to the resource instead.". But what about `python3.6`?